# Normal subgroup and conjugate classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

[image: Question]

My solution
[image]
I am not sure if my solution is correct .

Comment: You needed to show existence of a certain normal subgroup. I can't tell where you defined it (H).

Comment: Can you define it? I am not really sure how to define $H$ here

Comment: That's the crux of the problem and is probably worth stating more clearly. Background: given a normal subgroup $H$, $a\sim b$ iff $a^{-1}b\in H$ defines a congruence relation on $G$. Your problem is saying the converse holds-- any congruence relation arises from a normal subgroup in this way.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. The question as I understood is, that we are provided with a relation   $ \rho $ & a set H & asked to prove that this set H is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: No, that is not what the question is asking. Showing the existence of a normal subgroup which induces the relation $\rho$, is the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\rho$ be the congruence relation. We will denote $g_1\sim g_2$ to mean $(g_1,g_2)\in \rho$.

Define $H:= [e] = \{g\in G: g\sim e\}$, the equivalence class of the identity.

Your job is to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup, and that it induces $\rho$. Here is one step of that proof:

$H$ is *closed under conjugacy* because if $h\sim e$ then $gh \sim g$ and $ghg^{-1} \sim gg^{-1} = e$ by definition of a congruence relation.

So it remains to check that $H$ satisfies group axioms, and that $\rho = \{(a,b) \in G\times G |a^{-1}b \in H\}$.